# How do I upgrade "Promote This" to Movable Type 5?

Tags: movabletype

We just upgraded our Movable Type 4 Installation to Movable Type 5. One plug-in we were using is called Promote This. It hasn't been upgraded to MT5. Although it seems to work, the dashboard gives us a warning:

```
This plugin has not been upgraded to support Movable Type 5. As such, it may not be completely functional.
uses: MT::Template::Context::add_tag, should use: Registry (path: tags, function)
```

I really haven't programmed Perl for years. Is this a hard thing to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We created a [version of PromoteThis that is compatible with Movable Type 5](https://github.com/After6Services/mt-plugin-promotethis) in order to facilitate upgrades of older Movable Type-based sites, and
in order to avoid continued use of Movable Type 4.  Movable Type 4.38
is going End-Of-Life at the end of 2013.

We have successfully deployed this updated version on a site that we upgraded from MT 4.31 to 5.2.3, and I am not aware of any problems.

Feel free to try it and submit any bug reports to the repository if you find any issues that need to be addressed.

I will submit a pull request to Byrne Reese, so that his repository has a more current version.

Answer (score 0):

The author is Byrne Reese and I'm pretty sure he'll gladly update his plugin (it looks like a trivial change IMHO). Have you asked him?

Comment: Yes. It is trivial. You need to create the .yaml file, rename all of the subroutines, set them up, etc. Will probably take me 2 hours.